# Set keyname with spread operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

Is it possible to dynamically set key name to spread operator?

For example I have:

```
'first, second, third'.split(',');
// Array(3) : [ 'first', 'second', 'third' ]
```

I want to have an object like this

```
{ 'first': 'first', 'second': 'second', 'third': 'third' }
```

By doing this right now I get:

```
{ ...'first, second, third'.split(',') };
// { 1: 'first', 2: 'second', 3: 'third' }
```

Can I dynamically set it or I have to iterate through and do it manually at this point?

I've ended up combine the two answers to use this:

```
const toObject = str => Object.assign(...str.split(/\s*,\s*/).map(key => ({ [key]: key })));
```

Comment: You cannot spread an array into object keys.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jonas' solution is clever. I like it. Here's an alternative:

```js
function toObject(str) {
  const parts = str.split(/\s*,\s*/);
  return parts.reduce((obj, part) => {
    obj[part] = part;
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

console.log(toObject('first, second, third'));
```

Note that I use `split(/\s*,\s*/)` instead of `split(',')` to eliminate whitespace between parts.

This can be reduced to the following one-liner, if you're into that sort of thing:

```js
const toObject = str =>
  str.split(/\s*,\s*/).reduce((o, p) => (o[p] = p, o), {});

console.log(toObject('first, second, third'));
```

Comment: Also `str.split(",").map(x => x.trim())` - which eliminates whitespace in front and end of the string as well

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because you have the scenario for trimming space and of course one-liner :P

Answer (score 4):

You could spread a list of key/value pairs into object assign:

```
  Object.assign(...'first, second, third'.split(',').map(key => ({[key]: key})))
```